# Prove that set of all perfect numbers is primitive recursive

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

I have to prove that set of all perfect numbers is primitive recursive.
 Consider the characteristic function of the set:
$$ \chi(x)=\begin{cases}
1,  & x \text{ is perfect number} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
$$x \text{ is perfect number} \iff x=\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}k\cdot(k|x)$$

Last function is primitive recursive (as bounded sum, divisibility and multiplication are primitive recursive functions). Thus, the characteristic function of the set is primitive recursive function, so our set is primitive recursive. 
Am I right?

Comment: (a) Divisiblity test $k|x$ is primitive recursive, (b) Finite sum of a primitive recursive function are primitive recursive . Combining we obtain $\sum_{k=1}^{x-1} k (k | x)$ (the RHS) is, and so is (c) testing if the difference between $x$ and $ \sum_{k=1}^{x-1} k (k|x) $ is zero (signum function). See the list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function